# How can I Show an option to choose phone calling app by tapping on phone number in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, phone-call

I wants to show an option listing such as WhatsApp call, Skype call, Phone call, etc. by tap of phone number then user will choose any one. Right now I'm using flutter_launcher for call and it will works only for native phone call.

Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Comment: You would need to ask the user which calling app they want to use and then open the appropriate URL - `tel:` for the inbuilt phone or app specific urls for the other apps.

Comment: How can I know the other apps calling specific urls ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use UrlLauncher.launch('tel:...'), and let the phone operating system handle that the way the user set up his phone.

Users are already able to choose the default app for these kind of intents.

Comment: They can on Android perhaps, but not on ios

Comment: You're right, it's possible to choose the default web browser and email apps only. I thought it was the case for the phone app too !